# JSON.parse parses JSON.stringify output but not string itself

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I just got this in the Chrome console:

```
JSON.stringify(({wat:"\""}))
> "{"wat":"\""}"
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(({wat:"\""})))
> Object {wat: """}
JSON.parse('{"wat":"\""}')
> VM34235:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string in JSON at position 9(…)
```

Screenshot:

[image: shenanigans]

`JSON.parse` successfully parses when passed the output of `JSON.stringify({wat:"\""})` but throws when I try to eval `JSON.parse('{"wat":"\""}')`.

I'm calling shenanigans.

Comment: Look at the string value of `'{"wat":"\""}'`. It should be pretty clear then.

Comment: `'{"wat":"\""}' === '{"wat":"""}'; // true`, you need to escape your backslash

Comment: If you look at the console output (`"{"wat":"\""}"`), you can see that the value is not a valid string literal, because it doesn't show escape sequences. Otherwise it would have to look like `"{\"wat\":\"\\\"\"}"`. Hence you cannot simply copy and paste the output into a string literal. What the console shows you is the string **value**. This might become more obvious if you type `'foo\nbar'` into the console.

Comment: Yeah, I should have figured that out. I was debugging some code which put a stringified object into a template string which was eval'd later, and tried to parse the same, confused me enough to forget about proper escaping...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quote character has to be escaped with two backslashes, like that:

```
JSON.parse('{"wat":"\\""}')
```

When it's escaped with only one backslash, `JSON.parse()` actually gets the following value to parse:

```
{"wat":"""}
```

which is of course invalid JSON.

Comment: Can't he just add more double qoutes as well? \"""

Answer (score 0):

Try adding 2 backslashes like this. JS sees the \ as an escape character and ignores it. So:

```
{wat:"\\""}
```